# XQuery Full Text Search: Text Near Element?

Tags: lucene, full-text-search, xquery, exist-db

I am using the eXist implementation of Lucene. Is there a query that would allow me to find, for instance, all occurrences of `<span>A</span> B` in a document? I.e., all `B`s that occur within 1 word of `<span>A</span>`, but aren’t wrapped in their own elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XPath should do the trick:

```
//span[. = 'A'][following-sibling::node()[1] = ' B']
```

This doesn't make use of eXist's Lucene-based full text index, but you haven't said if you've applied an index to the span element here.  If there's another aspect to the challenge, please let me know.

Comment: This is close to what I’m looking for, but this only works when there’s no text content after “B”. What I meant was, how do I find that in the context of a larger document, which is why I assumed full text would be the answer (although maybe it isn’t). So presume something like `Lorem ipsum <span>A</span> B dolor amet; <span>C</span>.` Only want As and Bs that occur together in that order but nothing else.

Comment: I see.  I don't think full text is necessary here; in fact, it might complicate things.  If you're just looking for text content that starts with ' B...', how about using starts-with():  //span[. = 'A'][starts-with(following-sibling::node()[1], ' B')]